# laravel resource url depend on model?

Tags: laravel, routes, resources

i am run this command for model, migration, resource controller.  `php artisan make:model QuestionAnswer -mc -r` ..

**Resource Route**
`Route::resource('faq','QuestionAnswerController');`

**My Edit Function**

```
public function edit(QuestionAnswer $questionAnswer)
    {
        // return $questionAnswer;
        return view('backend.faq.edit',get_defined_vars());
    }
```

**Edit Route**
`{{route('admin.faq.edit',$questionAnswer->id)}}`

**Edit function `return $questionAnswer` return null**

**Below Picture**

[image]

[image]

**When i Change resource route like model name**
`Route::resource('question-answer','QuestionAnswerController');`

**edit function `return $questionAnswer` return `object` mean expected output ..**

**Picture**
[image]
[image]

***Question***

**laravel resource url  depend on model or something  ?
if i am wrong somewhere for `Route::resource('faq','QuestionAnswerController');`  please comment i will remove my question..**

Comment: `$questionAnswer` is not the correct param for your controller, you will find your parameter name with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: give me some thom to check

Comment: Or, you can assign the parameter name as `Route::resource('faq','QuestionAnswerController')->parameters(['questionAnswer' => 'questionAnswer']);`

Comment: @sta i put pic ..  please review my question..

Comment: I got you param name on your pic. your parameter is `{question_answer}`, so change the function to `public function edit(QuestionAnswer $question_answer)`

Comment: if you generate the controller `php artisan make:model QuestionAnswer -mcr` then your controller will be created correctly with the parameter, here `c` is for controller, `m` for migration, `r` for resource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225073/discussion-between-noor-and-sta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacause your route parameter is `question_answer`, so change the controller to :

```
public function edit(QuestionAnswer $question_answer)
{
   dd($question_answer);
}
```

Alternatively, you can specifically tell the resource what the route parameter should be named :

```
Route::resource('faq','QuestionAnswerController')
           ->parameters(['faq' => 'questionAnswer']);
```

Now you can access `$questionAnswer` as parameter :

```
public function edit(QuestionAnswer $questionAnswer)
{
   dd($questionAnswer);
}
```

The official documentation of **Naming Resource Route Parameters** will be found **[here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)**

Comment: any doc for this .. `->parameters(['questionAnswer' => 'questionAnswer']);` ?

Comment: Yes, I attached it on my answer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

Comment: it will be like `->parameters(['faq' => 'questionAnswer']);` .. update  your answer...

Comment: `$questionAnswer`  and `$question_answer` both are working for me...

Answer (score 1):

Laravel `resource` generate prams base on url example

```php
Route::resource('faq','QuestionAnswerController');

// this will generate url like

Route::get('faq','QuestionAnswerController@index')->name('faq,index');
Route::post('faq','QuestionAnswerController@store')->name('faq,store');
Route::get('faq/{faq}','QuestionAnswerController@show')->name('faq,show');
Route::put('faq/{faq}','QuestionAnswerController@update')->name('faq,update');
Route::delete('faq/{faq}','QuestionAnswerController@destroy')->name('faq,destroy');
```

so here in controller you need to accept that `faq` like this

```php
public function edit(QuestionAnswer $faq) // here $faq should match with route prams
{
        return $faq;
}
```

or you can change route url `faq` to `questionAnswer` then your old code will work

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: _Laravel resource generate prams base on url example_  where did you find ? any doc ? i am looking for study purpose ...would you can provide me ?